# How to provide container name in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to add the container name to docker-compose.yml so my container doesn't get a randomly generated name.

Answer (score 11):

Add `container_name` attribute to your `docker-compose.yml` file so it becomes:

`container_name: my_fancy_container_name`

More info here https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name